How to properly import packages in gradle.kts?
I have created new module and would like to configure it with data from local.properties.
I would like to import
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.gradleLocalProperties

or

import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.util.Properties

and every time I have an error:
No variants found for ':core'. Check [...]/myapp/core/build.gradle.kts to ensure at least one variant exists and address any sync warnings and errors. at:
com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidModule.prepare(GradleModules.kt:254)
 

Why it works like that?
I have used the newest approach with .toml
That's my settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "myapp"
include ':app'
include ':v2'
include ':domain'
include ':core'



Are u sure that core/build.gradle.kts is set up correctly?
For example for a library module it should begin with
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android")
}

since you are using .toml should looks like this
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.library)
}

If it is an Android module be sure it has a Android block with the configuration inside
android {
    compileSdk = 33 // Update as needed
    
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21 // Update as needed
        targetSdk = 33
    }
}

Dont forget to sync the project after the changes
